# Footer items don't appear with the existing preamble

Tags: header-footer, document-classes, footer

I cannot get the footer working with the following code. Any help in getting the desired footer is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage, bbding, pmboxdraw}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{.7,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,.6,0}
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{.98,0,0}
\usepackage[colorlinks,pagebackref,pdfusetitle,urlcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue,linkcolor=darkred,bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{longdivision}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{claim}{Claim}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fact}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{observation}[theorem]{Observation}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\number\numexpr\value{section}\relax}

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
%%%%%%%%%%%% LISTING %%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\usepackage{verbatim} % used to display code
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{acronym}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\VerbatimFootnotes % Required, otherwise verbatim does not work in footnotes!

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\footnotesize IEEE 2019}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Engineering Mechanics}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8 pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  letterpaper,
  lmargin=2 cm ,
  rmargin=1.4 cm,
  tmargin=2 cm,
  bmargin=2 cm,
  footskip=22 pt,
  headheight=12pt}  
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\linespread{1.4}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Comment: With the information you provided so far I can't reproduce the issue. Please prepare a complete small example document that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @leandriis, I have edited the question with \lipsum and as you can see I still cannot get the footer.

Comment: Remove `\pagestyle{myheadings}` and `\thispagestyle{empty}`, and set the geometry before you define the footer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it worked ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

seems fine

[image]

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage, bbding, pmboxdraw}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\footnotesize IEEE 2019}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Engineering Mechanics}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8 pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize \thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```